# SQL query with group by month and calculate AVG in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 field, A01, A02, time in SQL server
I'd like to know field about AVG(A01+A02) from 2013/6 to 2013/10
and time field's format is yyyymmddhhmmss(ex:20131202013000)
I want to group the result of AVG(A01+A02) by month
so it should be 5 result about this question

what sql query should it be?

Comment: Why are you storing your time as a string?

Comment: I don't know why, these database is from another place, and they store time format as this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer about this question, my friend told me try substring
and it works

SELECT  AVG(A01+A02)
FROM my_table
WHERE time BETWEEN '201305%'AND '201311%'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(time, 1, 6)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar in sql-server. But this may serve you.

```
SELECT convert(varchar(6), time, 112) as year_month, AVG(A01+A02)  as a_avg 
from yourtable GROUP BY year_month
```

I have created an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d9cd6/5) , see how this works.